# A Fold-like Brush in Sculpting?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

There's something I'm struggling to pull off in Sculpt Mode, I'm trying to create a type of, heavy fold, if you will. It's less like the folds or creases in clothing, and more of the type of fold you'd get if you, well, I don't know how to explain it, but this picture on Dictonary.com kind of is similar to what I'm trying to hit.

[image]

Those sharp, deep, weighed over folds in E, with the top of the mesh folding over the bottom part of it, still keeping an opening, but being, more like what's in the picture.

[image]

I've given three types of sculpting a shot, the left is thumb, with a smooth afterwards, the middle is grab with smooth, and the right is Snake Hook with smooth. None of them are, what I'm going for. The inward fold is non-existent, it's more like the top of the is melting over the bottom instead of creating a fold like the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could play with the Gravity factor in the Options tab, and that might enable you to get the kind of fold you want - I also suggest maybe using the Crease brush in opposite direction to raise the fold out of the mesh with the ctrl key and pressure stroke.

Comment: Wow! Never heard about this setting before. Thanks for your answer!